# django DurationField: Edit only hours and minutes in admin UI?

Tags: python, django

I have a `Recipe` model that has a few `DurationField` attributes:

```
class Recipe(models.Model):
    # ...
    prep_time    = models.DurationField(default=timedelta())
    cooking_time = models.DurationField(default=timedelta())
    total_time   = models.DurationField(default=timedelta())
```

On the django admin UI, I have the ability to edit the seconds field for these three attributes. Is there any way to limit an admin user to just be able to edit the hours/minutes of a `DurationField`? I don't really need this level of granularity here and am wondering if there's an alternative to storing the times purely as floats and then converting on my view.